# Podman compose reveal webserver to network (windows)

Tags: docker-compose, podman, podman-compose, podman-networking

I use podman compose on windows to run a webapplication. There I start an nginx container with 443 open. I can access the website on https://localhost/ but not on https://<my_ip_address>

How can i configure podman or the compose file so that i can access my_ip_address which is the ip from the windows host within the network? (Best would be if only the ngnx server is exposed)

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres-14:
    container_name: 'postgres-14'
    image: 'mycompany/my-app-postgres-14'
    restart: always

  my-app-django:
    container_name: 'my-app-django'
    image: 'mycompany/my-app'
    restart: always

  my-app-nginx:
    container_name: 'nginx'
    image: 'mycompany/my-app-nginx'
    restart: always
  ports:
     - "443:443"
```